# Подсчет количества ячеек со значениями больше 0 Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Есть диапазон ячеек, заполненный числами. Необходимо посчитать сколько ячеек содержат значение > 0 таким образом, чтобы это значение можно было использовать в скрипте в качестве максимального значения переменной. Прошу помочь разобраться

Comment: Разобраться в чем? Смотрите значение в каждой ячейке и считайте.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, советую изучить официальную [документацию](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) GAS. Там все очень неплохо структурировано и описано.

Общий алгоритм в вашем случае будет таков:

1. Получить значения нужного диапазона через [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
2. Пройтись по каждому элементу удобным для вас [циклом](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8B_%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) и через условие if подсчитать нужное Вам кол-во.

Comment: Иногда можно даже и цикл не делать, если воспользоваться готовой функцией [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480) с аргументом-условием ">0" и в скрипте брать результат из ячейки с этой функцией.

Comment: @АлександрЕрмолин, задача по скриптам, не вносите путаницу.

Comment: @oshliaer , читайте задачу внимательнее: "Необходимо посчитать ... таким образом, чтобы это значение **можно было использовать** в скрипте". Ирина не уточняет, какой способ подсчёта ей предпочтительнее.

Comment: @АлександрЕрмолин, не вносите путаницу.